# Kong: Running Mashape Kong fails on Mac OS X

Tags: cassandra, dnsmasq, mashape, kong

Today I installed [Kong](http://getkong.org) (API Management Layer) on my Mac OS X (Yosemite 10.10.5). I used the .pkg file which is [available here](http://getkong.org/download/#osx). I followed the installation instructions and everything was successful.

I also installed Cassandra using the information given on the Cassandra home page.

But when I start Kong, using the command:

```
$ kong start
```

It throws the following error:

```
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for fe80::3e15:XXXX:XXXX%en0: Can't assign requested address
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have already something running on the kong port 8000,8001 or 9042. Try to shut down anything that might be using those ports and retry?

Comment: No, in the mentioned ports only 9042 is only occupied. That too by Cassandra only. Other ports are free. Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure Kong to run on any custom ports for *(proxy and admin)* by changing the values in the `/etc/kong/kong.yml` file. see full config reference [here](http://getkong.org/docs/0.3.2/configuration/#proxy_port)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dnsmasq on Kong is listening by default on port `8053` (https://github.com/Mashape/kong/blob/master/kong.yml#L29), which seems to be already taken on your system.

Make sure that there is nothing else running on that port.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process that is running on the dnsmasq port and restart the kong.

Kill the process:

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:8053`
```

Start Kong:

```
kong start

/usr/local/bin/kong start
/usr/local/bin/kong stop
/usr/local/bin/kong reload
/usr/local/bin/kong status
```